# Have postfix to reply with 2 different hostnames?

Tags: postfix

How I do to make postfix to run on 2 different ports (25 and 26), and then reply with the banner "dns1.sebbe.eu SMTP ready" on port 25, and reply with the banner "dns2.sebbe.eu SMTP ready" on the port 26?

Else, all other processing should be the same, mail should be sent to same handler and so on.

The reason is restrictions in different services and registrar, requiring 2 mail servers, 2 DNS servers and so on.
So I just did so 2 different IPs Point to the exactly same machine, so those services stop complaining.

Comment: Is running two different invocations of the `postfix` daemon, with two different config files, out of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this via /etc/postfix/master.cf.

Add a separate transport for port 26 with the option myhostname=dns2.sebbe.eu.

I.e. change:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

to:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
26        inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
          -o myhostname=dns2.sebbe.eu
```

and then restart postfix.

But I would personally change it to:

```
193.13.142.178:smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
          -o myhostname=dns1.sebbe.eu
95.143.193.160:smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
          -o myhostname=dns2.sebbe.eu
```

So you have them listening directly to port 25 on the correct IP addresses.

Comment: however, the SMTP box is behind a multiWAN firewall, so the SMTP box itself does not know which IP the request received on. Thats why I need a different port, so I can NAT all requests arriving at 193. to port 25 on 192.168.1.x and NAT all requests arriving at 95. to port 26 on 192.168.1.x.